# Tensorflow fit ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (16640,)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I create a tf dataset from a tokenized text converted to sequences then numpy arrays

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(bible_text)#Builds the word index
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(bible_text)

##-->[[5, 1, 914, 32, 1352, 1, 214, 2, 1, 111],
## [2, 1, 111, 31, 252, 2091, 2, 1874, 2, 547, 31, 38, 1, 196, 3, 1, 899, 2, 1, 298, 3, 32, 878, 38, 1, 196, 3, 1, 266],
## [2, 32, 33, 79, 54, 16, 369, 2, 54, 31, 369], [2, 32, 215, 1, 369, 6, 17, 31, 156, 2, 32, 955, 1, 369, 34, 1, 547], ...]

sequences=pad_sequences(sequences, padding='post')

##-->[[   5    1  914   32 1352    1  214    2    1  111    0    0    0    0
##     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
##     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
##     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
##     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
##     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
##     0    0    0    0    0    0]
##...]

word_index=tokenizer.word_index 

##for k,v in sorted(word_index.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[:10]:
##   print (k,v)

##--> the 1
##and 2
##of 3
##to 4
##in 5
##that 6
##shall 7
##he 8
##lord 9
##his 10
##
##[...]

vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
```

building input and target sequences

```
input_sequences, target_sequences = sequences[:,:-1], sequences[:,1:]
seq_length=input_sequences.shape[1] ##-->89
num_verses=input_sequences.shape[0]

input_sequences=np.array(input_sequences)
target_sequences=np.array(target_sequences)
```

and the dataset

```
dataset= tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((input_sequences, target_sequences))
```

Nothing seems particularly wrong with this dataset setup. I define the model here

```
EPOCHS=2
BATCH_SIZE=256
VAL_FRAC=0.2  
LSTM_UNITS=1024
DENSE_UNITS=vocab_size
EMBEDDING_DIM=256
BUFFER_SIZE=10000

len_val=int(num_verses*VAL_FRAC)

#build validation dataset
validation_dataset = dataset.take(len_val)
validation_dataset = (
    validation_dataset
    .shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
    .padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
    .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE))

#build training dataset
train_dataset = dataset.skip(len_val)
train_dataset = (
    train_dataset
    .shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
    .padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
    .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE))

#build the model: 2 stacked LSTM
print('Build model...')
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, EMBEDDING_DIM))
model.add(LSTM(LSTM_UNITS, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(seq_length, vocab_size)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(DENSE_UNITS))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=loss,
              metrics=[
                  tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]
              )

model.summary()
```

I get the following error - it falls in the fit method

```
ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (16640,)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (256, 3067)).
```

Any idea, what can be wrong ?

EDIT

If I change to categorical_crossentropy for the loss I get

```
   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend.py:4839 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1161 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (256, 65) and (256, 3067) are incompatible
```

EDIT

I used the model indicated by AloneTogether and this solves the fitting step. But I run into a problem when doing the prediction on new data

```
preds = model.predict(x, verbose=0)[0][0]
```

since predictions do not sum exactly to one

```
>>> preds
array([1.6435336e-04, 1.4827750e-04, 1.4495676e-04, ..., 8.9204557e-05,
       8.9799374e-05, 8.7148059e-05], dtype=float32)
>>> sum(preds)
1.0000000457002898
```

which seems to be why I then can't sample from this 'distribution'

```
def sample(a, temperature=1.0):
    #helper function to sample an index from a probability array
    a = np.log(a) / temperature
    a = np.exp(a) / np.sum(np.exp(a))
    return np.argmax(np.random.multinomial(1, a, 1))
```

Any clue why this behavior, any workaround?

Comment: What are `next_words` in your example?

Comment: @AloneTogether thanks, I changed things a little bit, adding an Embedding layer and changing the way I build the sequences, dataset isn't empty any more but I fall into a shape issue

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what exactly is your use case?